# Cannot create a new partition for unallocated space using gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, unallocated

I know this question is a duplicate(s), but the possible fix given for other question doesn't really help. Here is view of my drive:

[image: see here]

What I want is to partition the unallocated space, but am told `Cannot create a new partition for my unallocated`. On another question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679329/cannot-extend-a-partition-located-after-the-unallocated-space), it's said to  *enlarge the Extended Partition /dev/sda4 by moving its left border to occupy all unallocated.* I tried  doing just that but it won't expand.

How can i enlarge the Extended Partition to engulf the unallocated space?

Comment: you will need to move the "empty" partition to the end of your extension. This will take a VERY long time.

Comment: @EODCraft Staff how do i do so?

Comment: Not that. The problem is you already have the maximum four primary partitions allowed for MBR partition type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question asked is that if you want to enlarge your Extended partition, you must first move *everything* to the left so that the unallocated space is after the Extended partition, at the end of the disk. then you can enlarge your Extended partition and create a new logical partition inside it. **However, this will be both lengthy and risky**, because data will need to be physically moved from one location on the disk to another. Also, since you will need to move your Windows partition, there is a possibility that Windows will get confused and refuse to boot.

There are two less drastic alternatives to consider.

- If your new partition is to be used in Linux, there is no need to create one, just enlarge your existing Linux partition. This would be quick and painless, because the free space is alteady to the right of it.
- Since your existing Extended partition only contains your swap partition, which does not store any data, you can just delete it and create a new one in the free space. Then inside it you would recreate a swap partition and then create your new logical partition (you would also need to modify your Linux system's `/etc/fstab` to use the new swap partition). The drawback is that you would then not be able to create anything in the free space where the old Extended partition was (but you could possibly enlarge your Windows partition over it).

Comment: 2nd alternative is better, but how do i recreate the swap partition and what modificaion will i have to do on /etc/fstab

Comment: Just create a new swap partition, gparted lets you do that. And in your fstab, replace the information (device node or UUID) of the old swap partition with that of the new one.